# Binding Multiple ng-model to a single HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created this table which can be filtered with the search box. I also want to highlight the term that was entered in the search box. So far, I got i t to work but in separate input boxes. It does the one but not the other.I guess I need to pass two ng-models to the input box in order to filter and highlight the matching term? Or Do I have to pass filter in ng-show?  This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/ZDWdH/2/  is very similar but it works on list. I tried that example but I guess it does not work on arrays. Please excuse any newbie errors.

Here is my angular code:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']).filter('highlight', function () {
  return function (text, search, caseSensitive) {
    if (search || angular.isNumber(search)) {
      text = text.toString();
      search = search.toString();
      if (caseSensitive) {
        return text.split(search).join('<span class="ui-match">' + search + '</span>');
      } else {
        return text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');
      }
    } else {
      return text;
    }
  };
});
app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,$http) {

 $scope.orderByField = 'Activity_ID';
  $scope.reverseSort = false;

$scope.items=[];//removes undefined length errors


    $scope.loadPeople = function() {
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://url_local/time/timesheet_json.php'

        }).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.items = data;
            console.log($scope.items);
        });

    };
$scope.loadPeople();
});
</script>

<html>
<input ng-model="query" />
<input ng-model="hightlightText"/> 
//Removed code to highlight specific sections
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort"    ng-show="([item] | filter:query).length">
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Matrix_ID | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Matrix_ID}}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_ID | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_ID  }}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Date | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Date}}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Category | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Category}}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Hours | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Hours}}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Project | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Project}}</td>
        <td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_Description | highlight:highlightText">{{item.Activity_Description}}</td>
</html>


JSON Response: [{"Activity_Matrix_ID":"163","Activity_ID":"131","Activity_Date":"2062-02-16","Activity_Category":"Maintanence","Activity_Project":"All Projects","Activity_Description":"Json data ","Activity_Hours":"2"},{"Activity_Matrix_ID":"161","Activity_ID":"129","Activity_Date":"2044-02-25","Activity_Category":"Tech Support","Activity_Project":"All Projects","Activity_Description":"Dummy dummy ","Activity_Hours":""}]
```

Comment: Hi Deepseas, would you please give us a sample of what your retrieve from 'https://url_local/time/timesheet_json.php' to help me answer to your question ?

Comment: Hi Charles, I have edited my question to add the JSON response. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code that I could see. The main one, is the binding should have been highlighting based on "query". See the following:

```
<td ng-bind-html="item.Activity_ID | highlight:query"></td>
```

I made this change as well as a few other changes in a plunkr which you can find here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yLYPnjyTpQZqoR1UE6yI?p=preview. Best of luck!

**Other Changes** (in the example)

- Newer versions of angular require "ngSanitize" to be included from a separate library.
- Added a css style for "ui-match" which wasn't in your question or in the example
- Cleaned up the html and since you are using "ng-bind-html" you don't need anything inside of the td tags
- Simplified the controller and added bogus (sample) data for a clear example

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions. Right on the target.